# Significance of factor variable that is an indicator for missing data

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, anova, factor-analysis

I read [here](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/missing-data-mechanism/) and elsewhere that one technique for dealing with `NA`s in a database is to create a dummy variable that is 1 if an observation (row) has no missing data in it and a 0 otherwise. However I do not understand how to test if this "missingness" is significant for predicting some numerical response variable (call it $Y$) when there are other numerical predictors. For example, if I have a numerical predictor `x` and my dummy factor variable (call it `missing`), I cannot do something like

`lm(Y ~ x * missing)`

because `lm()` automatically removes rows with missing data, so it then thinks `missing` only has one factor level (0) and throws an error. I could just call

`lm(Y ~ missing)`

but that seems like I am ignoring information from the numerical predictor `x`. What should one do in this case?

Comment: Have you considered multiple imputation? The package `mice` not only has a variety of imputation methods, but also allows you to inspect the quality of imputation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf You can then pool the models obtained from each individual imputation to obtain an estimate of `x`.

Comment: The method you're using is only useful if missingness correlates sufficiently with the response. `x * missing` means an interaction between the value of `x` and whether it was missing or not. You cannot estimate that without some imputation method for `x`.

Comment: Set missing = 0  if x is not missing, otherwise missing =1. Then set x = 0 if x is missing. Fit a model $ y \sim x + missing$.